# Measure theory integration question involving continuous function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Quick measure theory question. Given that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$. How would you show that if  $$\int_{\Omega}f \, dx = 0$$ Then $f = 0$ everywhere? Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not true in general: consider $n=1$, $\Omega=[0,2\pi]$ and $f=\sin$. Or any simmetric interval and an odd function.

Comment: You need one of the following: Either assume $f\geq 0$, or assume that $\int_E fdx = 0$ for all subsets $E\subset \Omega$. Without either hypothesis, your conclusion is false (as pointed out above).

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thanks for your responses. One quick question. If $f$ is summable function then is $\int f dx < \infty$ if and only if $f(x) < \infty$ almost everywhere?

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for response. How would you define a 'simmetric interval'? Also could you check the question I asked Prahlad if you have a chance.

Comment: @JohnJack with "a symmetric interval" I mean an interval of the form $(-a,a)$  for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. For your second question only one implication is true: if $\int fdx<\infty$ then $f(x)<\infty$ almost everywhere. However, if $f(x)=1/x$ then $f$ is finite a.e. but it is not integrable (and if $f$ is integrable, $\int fdx<\infty$ by definition)

Comment: @Brandon Okay thanks, so $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is also an example of a function which is Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable?  Is there a simple reason why it is not Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: The question, as stated, does not have an answer: we can't prove a false statement. If you no longer need this question, please delete it using the `delete` link under the post. Otherwise, please edit it into something that can be answered.